# RedirectToAction not working after successful jquery ajax post?

Tags: c#, jquery, post, asp.net-mvc-2, jquery-post

The following does not redirect my page:  Here is the MVC code:

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult GoHome()
    { 
         return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");   
    }
```

Here is the ajax post:

```
   $.support.cors = true;

            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "http://localhost/UserAccount/GoHome",
                dataType: 'json',
                crossDomain: true
            });
```

The post is successful and when it hists the GoHome action it does not redirect to the Index Action of the Home Controller.

Comment: `$.support.cors = true;` isn't needed. `crossDomain: true` isn't needed.

Answer (score 83):

You cannot redirect from an AJAX post.  You could return the URL you want to redirect the browser to however and redirect from Javascript.

**Controller**

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult GoHome()
{ 
     return Json(Url.Action("Index", "Home"));   
}
```

**Javascript**

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "http://localhost/UserAccount/GoHome",
    dataType: 'json',
    crossDomain: true,
    success: function (data) {
        window.location.href = data;
    }
});
```

Comment: Hi,  Is this mainly for security, so you can't redirect a users browser to some page that might have a malicious script?

Comment: @xaisoft i think it's more of a lack of functionality than a security decision.

Comment: @xaisoft No, it a HTTP limitation.  During a normal PRG (Post, Redirect, Get), the server receives a form POST, processes it and returns a HTTP 301/302 redirect to another page which the browser receives and follows.  JS/AJAX do not know how to handle a 301/302 redirect as it is expecting a HTTP 200 response with a payload (Json, HTML, text) attached with it.

Comment: If you wanted it to redirect, you should post using a basic form anyway.

Comment: @Tommy - I have an ajax post that calls one action method and if that is succesful, it makes another ajax post which is supposed to redirect.  How can I make the second call non-ajax?

Comment: @xaisoft - are you submitting a form on your second call?

Comment: @Tommy - The second call checks if a session is valid and is supposed to redirect the user to the homepage.

Comment: you can also use 
window.location.href = '@Url.Action("actionName","controllername")';

Comment: what if you want to change all model properties