# How to binding model with ajax correctly

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-ajax

I have question about passing values with ajax. I have done something like this:

```
 $('#zlozZamowienie').click(function () {
    var wycieczki = [];
    $("input[name=Id_wycieczki]:checked").each(function () {
        var id = $(this).attr('id');
        wycieczki.push(id);
    });


    var productModel = {

        Id_oferty: $("#Id_oferty").val(),
        Nazwa_oferty: $("#Nazwa_oferty").val(),
        Data_od: $("#Data_od").val(),
        Data_do: $("#Data_do").val(),
        Cena_za_miejsce: $("#Cena_za_miejsce").val(),
        iloscDni: $("#iloscDni").val(),
        SelectedKwaterunek: $("input:radio[name=SelectedKwaterunek]:checked").val(),
        IdWycieczek: wycieczki


    };

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: '@Url.Action("Szczegoly", "Oferta")',
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        data: JSON.stringify({ 'skomponowanaOferta': productModel}),

        dataType: "json",
        success: function () {
            alert('Success');
        },
        error: function (xhr) {
            alert(xhr.error);
        }

    });
    return false;




});
```

Szczegoly controller

```
  [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Szczegoly(SzczegolyOfertyViewModel skomponowanaOferta)
    {

        if (ModelState.IsValid) { 
           ...
            };
            TempData["Szczegoly"] = szczegoly; 
            return RedirectToAction("ZlozZamowienie", "Zamowienia");
        }
```

Zamowienia Controller

```
   public ActionResult ZlozZamowienie()
    {

        var skomponowanaOferta = (SzczegolyOfertyViewModel) TempData["Szczegoly"]; 
        SzczegolyOfertyViewModel podsumowanie = new SzczegolyOfertyViewModel();

        if (SprawdzWycieczki(skomponowanaOferta.IdWycieczek))
        {
           ...

           };

            return View(podsumowanie);
        }
```

Which is passing data correctly but because of this return false statement my button do not redirect me anywhere. When I change this return to true or just delete it, this ajax pass nulls. What am I doing wrong?

EDIT: I have error from ajax like this:
[image]

Comment: what's the target of `click` action, if its a link probably its redirectly first and then `click` handler is running if indeed the ajax is happening.

Comment: target of click action is HttpPost controller which  is redirecting to another controller by RedirectToAction. I passing this data between controllers using TempData.

Comment: I guess, If you are using AJAX you cant redirect the page from backend

Comment: Maybe after ajax call is returned in success, you can do `location.href="url"`

Comment: I copied my controllers to make things more clear.

Comment: I am not skilled in .net, I just commented from front end perspective.. maybe someone with .net can help

Comment: ok, thank you anyway :)

Answer (score 0):

Ok I found answer here
[RedirectToAction not working after successful jquery ajax post?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20011282/redirecttoaction-not-working-after-successful-jquery-ajax-post)

and then I add this to my ajax:

```
location.href="url"
```

like as @vinayakj said

Comment: Why on earth are you not just serializing your form - data: $('form').serialize()` and remove the `contentType` option. But using ajax when you actually want to redirect is just plain crazy and pointless extra overhead. Just do a normal submit!

Comment: easy, Im just trying to learn new things. Thank you for this advice!