# After getting the search value by Ajax, redirect to result another View

Tags: asp.net, ajax, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

The parameter, **search**, comes from **Index** view by Ajax post. After the search process I want to send the **employees** object to **Result** view. Result action and view are in the same controller and same view folder. But **RedirectToAction(employees)** doesn't affect. There is no problem about getting search value from view by Ajax or about getting corresponding employees from database, all of them are fine. [This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20011282/redirecttoaction-not-working-after-successful-jquery-ajax-post) says you cannot redirect from Ajax post. I don't know how can I redirect & send the employees object to Result view. I don't want to make this via ViewBag.

```
[HttpPost]
public async Task<IActionResult> Result([FromBody]string search)
{
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(search))
    {
        return NotFound();
    }

    IEnumerable<Employee> employees = await _context.Employees.Where(e => e.Surname == search).ToListAsync();
    return RedirectToAction("Index", employees);
}
```

---

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.SearchButton').on('click', function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var searchVal = $('.Search').val();
        console.log(searchVal);
        $.ajax(
        {
            type: 'POST',
            contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
            url: '@Url.Action("Index", "Employee")',
            data: JSON.stringify(searchVal),
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function (response) {                
                console.log(response);
            },
            error: function (response) {
                console.log(response.message);
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: So that post also says, that you can redirect from javascript by assigning redirect URL value to `window.location.href` (you can do this in the `success` callback).

Comment: @Set but how can I send the employees with redirection?

Comment: ok, my bad, this may help only if you can use query parameters. For POST data, you may construct and fill out a hidden `method=POST action="http://redirect_url" form` and submit. Look into  [Send POST data on redirect with Javascript/jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19064352/2833802)

Comment: I want to handle this by .NET MVC way. Any other way do you know?

Comment: @JamesP Yes, you're right I can do it by TempData, ViewBag etc. but I want to handle this more professional way(if there is a way like that).

Comment: @Orhun Since you are redirecting, what is the point of doing it in Ajax or normal POST method?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I created a Result view instead of trying to redirect to Index view, removed the HttpPost and FromBody attribute from Result action, changed the "return RedirectToAction("Index", employees)" to "return View(employee)"

```
public async Task<IActionResult> Result(string search)
{
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(search))
    {
        return NotFound();
    }

    IEnumerable<Employee> employees = await _context.Employees.Where(e => e.Surname == search).ToListAsync();
    return View(employees);
}
```

---

```
<input type="text" class="Search" placeholder="Search by surname" /><a class="SearchButton">Search</a>
```

---

Then delete the whole jQuery code and replace with this lines of code:

```
$(document).ready(function () { 
    $('.SearchButton').on('click', function (e) {
        window.location.href = '@Url.Action("Result")' + '/?search=' + $('.Search').val();
    });
});
```

Comment: Would you say this is an ideal method?