# async task controller not redirecting to action

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asynchronous, async-await

I have an async task action controller called Upload, which allows a user to upload a PDF file. The PDF file is processed and the information is stored in a db. After the controller processes the PDF I need it to redirect to a confirmation View. Currently after the Upload controller finishes, I get no server e.g. 404 error etc, it simply redirects to the same Upload View, instead of Confirmation View

Can anyone tell me why? I'm pretty sure it has something to do with async tasks, maybe async tasks need to be redirected in a different way?

My Upload & Confirmation Actions in CompletedCamps Controller

```
        public ActionResult Upload(int? id)
        {
            CompletedCamp completedCamp = db.CompletedCamps.Find(id);
            return View(completedCamp);
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public async Task<ActionResult> Upload(HttpPostedFileBase file, int? id)
        {
            CompletedCamp completedCamp = db.CompletedCamps.Find(id);

            string filename = Guid.NewGuid() + Path.GetExtension(file.FileName);
            string filepath = Server.MapPath(Path.Combine("~/Surveys/", filename));
            file.SaveAs(filepath);

            completedCamp.SurveyName = filename;
            db.SaveChanges();

            await AzureVisionAPI.ExtractToTextFile(filepath);
            ParseSurveyText parse1 = new ParseSurveyText();
            await Task.Run(() => parse1.ParseTextFile(completedCamp.RollNumber, completedCamp.OfficialSchoolName, completedCamp.Date, filepath));

            return RedirectToAction("Confirmation", "CompletedCamps", new { id = id });
        }

        [HttpGet]
        public ActionResult Confirmation(int? id)
        {
            var camp = db.CompletedCamps.FirstOrDefault(c => c.Id == id);
            return View(camp);
        }
```

Comment: Is your Controller name "CompletedCamps"?

Comment: It sure is: "public class CompletedCampsController : Controller". I get no server errors.. no 404 nothing. It just returns the same Upload view

Comment: If you want redirect to Confirmation Controller you should change" CompletedCamps "to "confirmation"

Comment: `return RedirectToAction("Confirmation", "Confirmation", new { id = id });` please test this part instead of your code.

Comment: are you posting the PDF via ajax? if so, check this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/20011363/9533368

Comment: no ajax being used. I just tried this Json(Url.Action) method just to make sure it didn't solve my problem, still the same outcome

Comment: Double check if you are using `Post` and not a get request, see if it actually does what you think it does. See if pdf get saved correctly.

Comment: @MatJ Everything inside the method works fine. The Surveys get uploaded and the data from the surveys gets entered into the database. At this time the page should be redirected to the Confirmation View, instead it looks like it directs to the Upload View again

Comment: Like I said, Can you check the network tab of your browser and see what is the response received, Is it a `302` or a `200`? Remember to check the `Preserve logs` checkbox while you are at it.

Comment: Have you checked your RouteConfig just in case the problem is in there?

Comment: If you comment out the contents of your post Upload method bar the redirect is the behaviour the same?

Comment: Hi @DaveBarnett, if i comment out the contents of the post Upload method then the redirect works correctly. So I think I was right in saying that something in the async code is causing the problem? Is it strange that this problem doesn't occur when the app is deployed?

Comment: @MatJ I can't see anything obviously incorrect in the network tab

Comment: what if you set a break point in the post upload method and step through it.  Does it reach the Redirect code without problem?

Comment: Is it a particular await that's causing it?  Maybe this time comment out half of it and see if it works then.  If possible try to narrow down which bit is responsible.  I tried this with Task.Delay and it worked so I think there is more to it than it just being async.

Comment: What version of the .net framework are you targetting?

Comment: There is a lot going on within these 2 methods e.g. 2 API calls with a lot of data returned and some pixel manipulation of Bitmap objects, all of which depend on the last part to finish successfully. So unfortunately I can't test parts of them on their own. It is targeting .NET Framework 4.7.2. Out of curiosity, where did you put a task delay for it to work?

Answer (score 0):

If you want redirect to `Confirmation Controller` and `Confirmation Action` ,please test this code,
 instead of

```
return RedirectToAction("Confirmation", "CompletedCamps", new { id = id });
```

Use this code

```
return RedirectToAction("Confirmation", "Confirmation", new { id = id });
```

Comment: The controller name is CompletedCamps. Action names are Upload and Confirmation

Comment: It's not difference between async action in `RedirectToAction( ActionName ,ControllerName,new {id=id})`